# Exposed Service unreachable

Tags: docker, kubernetes, concourse

I am trying to run the following Kubernetes module which builds a Concourse Web UI & Scheduler along with the Postgresql dependency through this:

https://github.com/vyshane/concourse-kubernetes

However, the issue I am having is that expose mechanism isn't working, so I am only able to access the service from inside the Kubernetes, i.e.

```
<a href="/login?redirect=%2F">Found</a>
```

is returned from a curl on IP:forwadedPort. However, attempting to access the IP:forwadedPort results in a timeout each time. I also tried the following in the startup script:

```
kubectl expose service concourse-web --port=8080 --target-port=31080 --name=concourse-forward
```

and I receive similar results. Am I missing something in my setup? Syntax seems correct, and I get no syntax related errors, I know the Concourse service is in fact running, and I can the service and pod details to indicate it's fully functioning. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you clarify 'IP' is this the Service IP, the Pod IP, or the Node IP? Are you using a load balancer/ingress controller? If not, you will probably want to expose nodePort in the service. can you give the service YAML? 'kubectl get service concourse-web -o yaml'

Comment: `apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2016-07-08T07:23:16Z
  name: concourse-web
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "48"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/services/concourse-web
  uid: d6b2a4f8-44dc-11e6-8ee2-aa6ef233d78c
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.0.0.74
  ports:
  - name: atc
    nodePort: 31080
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  - name: tsa
    nodePort: 30194
    port: 2222
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 2222
  selector:
    name: concourse-web
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort
status:
  loadBalancer: {}`

Comment: This might be easier to read:

http://pastebin.com/0hv9q9Lf